# Best strategy for uploading multiple files

Tags: php, javascript, forms, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have a form to which one or more (big) files can be attached. I want to achieve the following:

- File uploading progress must be shown to the user
- The upload process can be interrupted by the user at any time
- If an error occurs with other data on the form after submitting it, files shouldn't be requested again; in other words, files are uploaded only once even though the form can be re-submitted multiple times
- If the files and form data are posted separately and independently through Ajax, the uploaded but unused files should be automatically purged
- Security considerations: e.g. if files are sent separately there shouldn't be a way for a malicious attacker to overwrite files on the server by knowing the session ID or other info available in the browser
- Browser requirements: the latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox; IE9 is desirable
- Server side: please don't suggest 3rd party frameworks; the solution should be so universal that it would enable anyone to implement it in their favorite language - Python, Ruby, PHP, Perl, etc. (and presumably JavaScript)

Considering the above, what are some tips and tricks and best practices for implementing this functionality?

Comment: So you want your users to be able to select multiple files in the select file window, right?

Comment: @Julien Bourdon: that's not required, although I know it's possible in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

swfupload is pretty awesome.  Well documented and works very well.  http://swfupload.org/

Comment: That's the answer I was going to propose. From my own experience, that's the only reliable solution.

Comment: To my understanding, again, it doesn't cover the server side of things.

Comment: True, but it doesn't impose any requirements or restrictions on the server side either, which is how I read your last bullet.  You can use whatever you want.

Comment: Also, if you go to the downloads tab, you'll see that some of the server-side code has been implemented for various backends.  Certainly you can extract what you need from these files, especially the CakePHP download, since you suggest you're using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If your users use the latest versions of the browsers you can use HTML5 file access from JavaScript.

You can look here for start http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Also you can take a look on my plugin for ruby on rails here (there are no docs yet, but JS code is rather simple) http://github.com/Ximik/simple_attachments

Comment: I've seen this before, it's a nice tutorial but it doesn't talk about the server-side strategies, e.g. where and how to store (and purge) the files, how to tie them to a form instance in case of multiple re-submits and so on.

Comment: Then really look at my code if you use rails. Most of this is done there or will be done in few days.

Answer (score 0):

I find this one pretty awesome, if you're ok with using jQuery - http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/